# robot framework + appium is unable to access element by ID in ionic angular application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, automated-tests, appium, robotframework

I am using Robot framework + Appium library  for automation testing of ionic app . developer team assigns id to components . but when i am giving click element id command then there is error . unable to find that element . is there any different way to access ionic component in appium ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please share your related codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is you need exact way of using resource-id in appium. 
I have used resource-id with with xpath and it is working great.

you need to find exact resource-id from elements in appium and then make xpath with that ID.

For example: let say your div has ID `"stackOverFlowDivId"`.
then your xpath will be : 
`xpath=//*[@resource-id='stackOverFlowDivId']`

Use this method and try finding xpath in appium.

Hope you get success. Best luck.